# Is it possible to add a custom validation message to my required field?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, error-messaging, required-field

I have an EditForm with some InputText. Some of the textboxes are required and as such in their class are declared using the [Required]. However some of them also have a [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Forename is too long")]. When the forename is too long in the textbox then the message below is as I have written it 'Forename is too long'. When I have a RegularExpression  [RegularExpression(@"^\w+[.]\w+[@]\w+[.]\w+$",
ErrorMessage = "Email must follow fred.example@live.com structure")]. Then the error message is 'Email must follow fred.example@live.com structure'. So I though it would be easy to add some validation to the [Required] by putting : [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]. However the message displayed is 'The Surname field is required.'. How can I edit this message because what I have done has clearly not done the job.

```
<EditForm Model=@newUser OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    @*    <ValidationSummary/>*@

    <label for="userForename">Forename:</label>
    <InputText id="userForename" @bind-Value="@newUser.Forename"></InputText>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => newUser.Forename)" />

    <label for="userSurname">Surname:</label>
    <InputText id="userSurname" @bind-Value="@newUser.Surname"></InputText>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => newUser.Surname)" />

    <label for="userEmailAddress">Email Address:</label>
    <InputText id="userEmailAddress" @bind-Value="@newUser.EmailAddress"></InputText>
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => newUser.EmailAddress)" />
        
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Add</button>

</EditForm>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a class for the TextInput. Then, in the class, you should add `[Required(ErrorMessage = "ERROR MESSAGE")]` and delete `<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newUser.Forename)" />`. Then you can delete `@*    <ValidationSummary/>*@`.

If you want some more, you can visit  [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)